# How to Use FontAwesome Icon without Changing Text Font

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin, font-awesome

I'm placing icons in buttons and labels but this is the result:

[image]

The icon is displayed but it changes the text. How can I display the icon without changing the text?

```
<Button x:Name="btnItems" Text="&#xf022; Load Items" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Button` can have `Text` and one `ImageSource` with `FontImageSource`:

`ContentLayout` sets position and spacing of image relative to text with default values shown in below XAML.

Possible position values are `Left`, `Right`, `Top`, `Bottom`.

With position values `Left` or `Right` text is vertically centered.

With position values `Top` or `Bottom` text is horizontally centered.

```
  <Button Text="fa-list" ContentLayout="Left, 10">
    <Button.ImageSource>
      <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xf022;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FaRegular4}"/>
    </Button.ImageSource>
  </Button>
```

`Label` can have one or more `Span`:

```
    <Label>
      <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
          <Span Text="f0A4 " />
          <Span Text="&#xf0A4;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FaRegular4}" />
          <Span Text=" f0A5 " />
          <Span Text="&#xf0A5;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FaRegular4}" />
        </FormattedString>
      </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
```

Comment: This works! However, the icon is all the way to the left and text is centered. How can I center the icon to align with the text?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way is to use button Image instead.
Download the Icon and add it to your Resources folder in iOS and Drawable in Android.
[image: Download image from Fontawesome's website]

And then use it in your button like this:

```
<Button Text="Edit" ImageSource="edit_icon" />
```

BTW, you need to change the button's font to something else or just leave the default.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I can thought is separate the icon and text:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Purple">

    <Button Text="&#xf0e2;" FontFamily="FontAwesome" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="25" HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />

    <Label Text="Load Items" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="90"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />

</StackLayout>
```